# Is there any difference between list[1] and list[1:2] in python?

Tags: python, list

I know that `list[1:2]` and `list[1]` codes shows only first item of list but in my whole code there is something wrong about it:

```py
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
count = dict()
max_amount = None
max_sender = None
    
for lines in handle :
    lines.strip()
    if lines.startswith('From:') : continue
    if lines.startswith('From') :
        words = lines.split()
        for word in words :
            if word == words[1] :
                count[word] = count.get(word, 0) + 1

for word, count in count.items():
    if max_amount is None or count > max_amount :
        max_amount = count
        max_sender = word

print(max_sender, max_amount)
```

this script executes corretly but this one not:

```py
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
count = dict()
max_amount = None
max_sender = None

for lines in handle :
    lines.strip()
    if lines.startswith('From:') : continue
    if lines.startswith('From') :
        words = lines.split()
        for word in words :
            if word == words[1:2] :
                count[word] = count.get(word, 0) + 1
    
for word, count in count.items():
    if max_amount is None or count > max_amount :
        max_amount = count
        max_sender = word
    
print(max_sender, max_amount)
```

Please focus on line 14 of both script.

Comment: `[1]` actually returns the _second_ element. The first element is `[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`words[1:2]` returns a list object where as `words[1]` returns the element of the list and that causes the main difference in the comparison with `==`.

You could use `words[1:2][0]` to get the element.

Comment: You were quicker ^^

Comment: @kaya-lab, I can understand that it can be confusing sometimes and adding `print(type(obj))` helps in these things.

Answer (score 1):

`words[1]` will return an element of the list, while `words[1:2]` will give you a list containing one element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The datatype can be different (if it is not a list containing multiple lists). Let's say you only have a list of numbers (integers). The following gives you only one value (in this case 2 as an integer):

```
print([1,2,3][1])
```

If you look at the output of the following, you'll see that you are getting a list (in this case [2]):

```
print([1,2,3][1:2])
```